# Unexpected behaviour of inverse_name in Odoo 11

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

You know about `inverse_name` parameter, available for One2many fields. It just tells Odoo which is the mandatory Many2one field in the related comodel to know the records to show.

In standard module **account**, in `account.invoice` model, there is a Many2one field named `move_id`. It is related to `account.move` model and its purpose is to show the journal entry generated for the invoice when this one is validated.

The only thing I want to do is to show in journal entries form (`account.move`) the invoice (`account.invoice`) whose validation has generated that journal entry. So it looked easy for me, I have just created the *other part* of the relationship in `account.move` model:

```
invoice_ids = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name='account.invoice',
    inverse_name='move_id',
    string='Invoices whose validation generated this journal entry',
)
```

The logical between `account.invoice` and `account.move` should be 1:1, but for this case I can use 1:N since the One2many is just informative and readonly for users. So this one seemed to work OK, I was able to see the invoice in the journal entry, but after a while I realised that I had destroyed the workflow with that code.

This is what happens now, I describe it with examples:

1. I create and validate the invoice *SALE/INV/00001*.
2. The validation generates the journal entry *2019/00001*. I can see this journal entry in the invoice form, and I can see the invoice in the journal entry form (in the One2many I have created). Right.
3. I pay the invoice, and here is where everything breaks down. The payment generates the journal entry *2019/00002*, which is OK, but now, in the invoice *SALE/INV/00001*, I see this journal entry instead of *2019/00001*, which is wrong, and if I go to the form of the journal entry *2019/00001*, the One2many field I have created to show the related invoice is empty, whereas the one in the journal entry generated by the payment shows *SALE/INV/00001*, when it should be empty.

I expected journal entry's `invoice_ids` field to show only the invoices whose validation generated that journal entry, since `move_id` in invoices only shows the journal entries generated by validations.

To correct this I have replaced the One2many `invoice_ids` by the Many2one `invoice_id` in journal entry, and I fill this in automatically in `account.move` ORM create method. But this solution does not link old records in the database, and I still do not understand the behaviour of the code described above.

So, does anyone have an explanation for that? I would like to know why `inverse_name` behaves like that.

Comment: If it really changes the `move_id` on payment on that invoice try to debug into that write process to see where that is coming from.

Comment: @CZoellner yes, after debugging a lot I could find the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After wasting a lot of time filling in the core with log messages, I found my unfortunate problem.

When you pay an invoice through the standard method (clicking on the *Register Payment* button), a pop-up of the `account.payment` model is opened. This model has already a field named `invoice_ids`, and Odoo is using the context of the action which opens the pop-up to fill it in automatically with the current invoice:

```
<field name="context">{'default_invoice_ids': [(4, active_id, None)]}</field>
```

When the payment is accepted, a call to `account.move` create method is done to generate the payment journal entry. The problem is that the context of the action still remains in that call, which means that Odoo thinks that I want to fill in my custom field `invoice_ids` of `account.move` with that value (which is always the active id, the invoice we keep opened)... and that is not the truth.

I guess that is very bad luck.

Finally I fixed it just modifying the technical name of my One2many field to avoid Odoo to be confused:

```
validated_invoice_ids = fields.One2many(
    comodel_name='account.invoice',
    inverse_name='move_id',
    string='Invoices whose validation generated this journal entry',
)
```

Comment: haha, yes i guessed some `default_` problem here, but was to lazy to search for it. There is a little discussion on that topic [in the Odoo issues](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/31777)

Comment: LoL it's really a bad luck